# Por que não existe mais o acento diferencial em palavras homográficas? (para / para)

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico, acentuação

Pela nova reforma ortográfica da língua portuguesa não existe mais acento diferencial em palavras homográficas.

> Exemplo:
>   Para (verbo) = Para (preposição)
>   Pelo (substantivo) = Pelo (contração)

A forma escrita do verbo "para" ficou idêntica à preposição "para".

É claro que dependendo do contexto podemos diferenciar o verbo da preposição.

Mas isso não gera dúvidas em alguns casos?

Por exemplo se uso "para" de forma isolada em um chat.

Comment: Evite utilizar de forma isolada

Comment: Adenda: em Portugal essas duas palavras não são homógrafas.

Comment: Com o acordo ortográfico ficaram homógrafas "para(verbo)/para(preposição)". Na pergunta está a forma antiga, mas retirei.

Comment: Gera dúvidas? Sim, às vezes. Por que caiu? Porque quem decidiu isso também é humano e às vezes toma decisões ruins. E também é humano evitar admitir o erro :-(

Comment: Em caso de dúvida, coloca-se o acento. Aqui há uns tempos houve uma publicidade para o canal do Benfica cujo slogan era 'pára tudo'. Se se parasse para ler as letras miudinhas, via-se que tudo no poster respeitava o acordo ortográfico... excepto, claro, a mensagem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Na verdade [alguns acentos diferenciais](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/novaortografia.php) como **por** (preposição) e **pôr** (verbo) ou **pôde** (pretérito perfeito do indicativo do verbo poder) e **pode** (presente do indicativo do verbo poder) foram mantidos. Também foram mantidos os acentos que diferenciam o singular do plural dos verbos **ter** e **vir**.

Todas alterações introduzidas com o novo acordo ortográfico tiveram como objetivo a (pretensa) unificação ortográfica dos países que *têm* (olha só um uso de acento diferencial!) a língua portuguesa como idioma oficial. Deve ter se acreditado que esta unificação fosse mais benéfica que eventuais dúvidas na escrita.

Comment: +1 por (pretensa)

Comment: Nunca percebi o alarido com a supressão de _alguns_ acentos diferenciais para palavras homógrafas não homófonas, quando tal é prática na língua muito antes do AO90 e já então levantando ambiguidades. Vejamos: `acordo com a minha mulher` É o acordo a primeira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo do verbo acordar, ou seja sair do sono; ou refere-se unicamente ao substantivo referente ao entendimento entre duas pessoas?

Answer (score 6):

O objetivo principal do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 foi unificar as grafias. Mas neste caso as palavras alteradas já antes tinham grafia igual em todos os países lusófonos, pelo que o motivo foi apenas simplificar as grafias. As palavras afetadas estão listadas abaixo (com links ao Priberam) na grafia antiga; na grafia do AO 90 escrevem-se todas sem acento:

> ***pára*** (de *parar*) e ***para*** (preposição)
>   [***péla***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pela) (‘bola’), ***péla, pélo*** (de *pelar*) e ***pela, pelo*** (contração de preposição com artigo)
>   ***pêlo*** (‘cabelo’) e ***pelo*** (contração de preposição com artigo)
>   ***pêra*** (fruto), [***péra***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pera) (forma antiquada de *pedra*) e ***pera*** (preposição antiga)
>   [***pólo***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/polo) (vários substantivos) e ***polo*** (antigo; agora *pelo, por o*)

Um [anexo da lei portuguesa do Acordo Ortográfico](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990b) apresenta alguns princípios e motivos que orientaram as alterações. Acerca desta supressão, diz  (ponto 4.1) que ela é coerente com a reforma de 1971 no Brasil e de 1945 em Portugal, as quais aboliram acentos diferencias em casos semelhantes; por exemplo os substantivos que na grafia anterior a essas reformas se escrevia *(o) acôrdo* e *(o) acêrto*, e que com a eliminação do acento passaram a ser homógrafos de *(eu) acordo, (eu) acerto*. Diz ainda que as palavras que se tornam homógrafas com a supressão destes acentos pertencem a classes gramaticais diferentes, o que facilita a identificação do seu significado.

No entanto, confusões são sempre possíveis. Houve aqui em Portugal quem facetamente apontasse que a frase seguinte fica agora ambígua:

> Alto… e para o baile!

Na atual grafia isto tanto pode querer dizer ‘alto… e vamos para o baile’ ou ‘alto… e que pare o baile’. Quer-me parecer no entanto que não há motivo para grandes preocupações. A verdade é que mesmo na grafia pré-AO 90 estes acentos diferenciais (em paroxítonas) eram exceções entre as centenas de pares ou mesmo ternos de palavras homógrafas e homónimas sem acentos diferenciais, e que nós compreendemos sem problemas pelo contexto. Deixo aqui uns exemplos:

> **Era** uma **era** turbulenta.
>   **Sede** vigilante: há uma grande **sede** de poder na **sede** do Partido Revolucionário.
>   **Chama** a **ateia** que **ateia** a **chama**.
>   Não **cobres** muito por esse **cobre** que já nada **cobre**.
>   Encontrei-o no caminho, quando **vinha** da **vinha**.
>   Disse-lhes que não **vale** a pena descer ao **vale**.
>   Mas eles **vão**. Em **vão**.
>   Mesmo de **luto**, **luto**.

Comment: Muito interessante essa do acôrdo e acêrto, nunca tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Há resmas de casos desses (não tenho a certeza se se usava acento diferencial, mas eu vou usar para ilustrar): *o gôsto, eu gosto; o encôsto, eu encosto; o apêrto, eu aperto, o consêrto, eu conserto, o entêrro, eu enterro, o tempêro, eu tempero; o desespêro, eu desespero*.

Comment: Atenção que `era` (substantivo) e `era` (forma verbal do verbo ser), e muitos dos outros exemplos, já são também pares homófonos, o que não é o caso de `para` e `pára`. De facto julgo que houve uma pequena revisão atual ao AO90 que tratou exatamente deste tópico.

Comment: @João, é verdade, e eu refiro-o no texto; o ponto é que a supressão dos raros acentos diferenciais da grafia pré-AO80 dificilmente gerará confusão, uma vez que nós conseguimos facilmente identificar a palavra pretendida em pares de homónimos ou homógrafos.

Comment: Verdade! Até porque antes do AO90 tal já acontecia. `acordo com a minha mulher` É o `acordo` a primeira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo do verbo acordar, ou seja sair do sono; ou refere-se unicamente ao substantivo referente ao entendimento entre duas pessoas?

Answer (score 0):

Vejamos:

Os acentos diferenciais servem para distinguir graficamente formas idênticas de palavras pertencentes a categorias gramaticais diferentes.

Exemplos de palavras alteradas por este Acordo Ortográfico são:

1. pelo: (contração da preposição latina per + artigo  masculino singular o) ;
2. pêlo: substantivo comum, masculino;
3. pêra: substantivo;
4. pára: verbo;
5. para: preposiçâo;
6. pólo: extremidade

Comment: Quanta incongruência. E pensar que existam pessoas que pensem que um idioma não se possa orientar, até mesmo na ortografia, em direção à Fonética que também é importantíssima.

Comment: O ser humano adora tomar decisões que não imediatamente, mas a longo prazo, danificam a si mesmo e ao próximo. O dano não é só físico, mas pode ser de várias formas, inclusive ideológicas.

Comment: Às vezer, muma frase, estas palavras como se escrevem atualmente, podem parecer-se trocadilhos.