# Qual é a origem do sinal gráfico circunflexo?

Tags: ortografia, gramática, origem-histórica, acentuação, escrita

*O nome do diacrítico procede do latim circumflexus (dobrado em torno de) - tradução do grego perispomene (περισπωμένη)*

[Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_circunflexo)

Circunflexo: Acento que denota o fechamento das vogais a, e, o (português) ou nasalização, quando precedida de m ou n;

Exemplos: *âmbar, pêssego e fenômeno*

É usado em outros idiomas, tais como:

**francês**: indica geralmente a supressão da letra s;

**italiano**: denota a formação dos singulares dos adjetivos terminados em -io, terminando certas palavras com i longo ou jota. O italiano atual emprega duas letras  ou uma letra i somente:
  Exemplos:  vario: varj, vari ou varii;

Observação: De acordo com a Wikipédia:

> É às vezes empregado para distinguir certas palavras, como por exemplo por e pôr. Seu uso tem sido bastante reduzido como conseqüência das reformas ortográficas.

Outros idiomas podem usá-lo de formas diferentes, tais como: o inglês,  no empréstimo de palavras estrangeiras, que o usam na palavra original: *rôle (posição social)*, *aôut (agosto)*;

Em eslovaco (em eslovaco vokáň) transforma a letra o no ditongo ô /u̯o/.

Comment: Tuca, estou aqui a pensar em qual será o tag mais apropriado. Etimologia é origem de palavras; não sei se se aplica a acentos. Mas nós temos o tag «origem-histórica» que me parece que ficaria bem aqui.

Comment: É verdade. A coisa é que eu quero conseguir mais pontos, mas eu mesmo não consigo achar termos apropriados para qualquer questão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como quase tudo na civilização ocidental, parece, o acento circunflexo também é uma invenção dos Antigos Gregos. Surgiu no período helenístico, literalmente do encontro do acento agudo (´) com o grave (`). No grego antigo uma vogal era acentuada sendo proferida, não com mais força como entre nós, mas em tom mais agudo. Na escrita marcava-se com o acento agudo as vogais acentuadas, e com o grave as não acentuadas. Quando uma vogal acentuada seguida de uma não acentuada formavam por contração uma única vogal longa, esta era grafada com acento circunflexo, e era proferida num tom descendente, de agudo para grave. [(*Circumflex* na Wikipedia em inglês.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex)

O acento circunflexo é reaproveitado nas línguas modernas europeias a partir do século XVI. O primeiro exemplo que se conhece é na obra de [Jacques Dubois (1478-1555), conhecido por *Sylvius* (Wikipédia em francês)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Dubois_(m%C3%A9decin)). Outros franceses se lhe seguiram, cada um usando o circunflexo para fins diversos. Só no século XVIII se normalizou um uso próximo do atual, que consiste em assinalar a supressão de uma letra, tipicamente um *s*—*tête* é cognato de *testa*, *forêt* é *floresta*. [(*Accent circonflexe en français* na Wikipédia em francês.)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_circonflexe_en_fran%C3%A7ais)

No português a aparição do acento circunflexo também não tardou. O primeiro uso de que tenho conhecimento é de 1576, na [*Orthographia da Lingoa Portuguesa* de Duarte Nunez de Lião](http://purl.pt/15/4/res-277-2-v_PDF/res-277-2-v_PDF_24-C-R0150/res-277-2-v_0000_rosto-78v_t24-C-R0150.pdf). O autor preconiza o seu uso, não para indicar a sílaba tónica, mas exclusivamente para distinguir palavras que doutro modo seriam homógrafas (f. 66)

[image]

Mas algumas sugestões são no entanto deveras curiosas (f. 67):

[image]

Não sei se a último ***a*** de *amará, ouvirá*, etc. teria na altura um timbre diferente do atual? Mas nunca vi em qualquer outro texto *amarâ, ouvirâ*, etc. Saltando para o século XIX, encontra-se um uso dos acentos que corresponde mais ou menos à ideia de Duarte Nunez: não para assinalar a sílaba tónica, mas para distinguir palavras que doutro modo seriam homógrafas, assinalando o circunflexo os sons fechados. Assim escrevia-se *amára* e *amará*; *comêra* e *comerá*; *pôr*, verbo, e *por*, preposição. Mas a situação era confusa, porque parece que cada pessoa escrevia à sua maneira. Isso mesmo nota em 1871 Domingos Vieira no seu monumental *Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* (verbete *circumflexo*)

> —Termo de Grammatica romanica. *Accento* **circumflexo**, signal orthographico em fórma de pequeno **v** voltado (^), que tem usos diversos conforme as linguas romanicas que o empregam. Em portuguez o accento circumflexo serve para indicar unicamente que a vogal sobre que se coloca é fechada, assim em *vêl-o, pômo*; mas ha a maior arbitrariedade em pôr ou não o *accento* **circumflexo** sobre as vogaes fechadas. N’isto, como em tudo, se revela o estado cahotico da nossa orthographia miseravel e preguiçosa.

O próprio *Thesouro* de Domingos Vieira é um exemplo do estado caótico da ortografia. Nele encontramos palavras como *(em) tôrno* e *(o) entêrro*, presumivelmente para se distinguirem de *(eu) torno* e *(eu) enterro*; mas também *(o) emprego* e *(o) acordo*, sem acento circunflexo para as distinguir de *(eu) emprego* e *(eu) acordo*. Por outro lado encontramos o acento circunflexo em vogais que, pelo menos no meu sotaque, têm timbre aberto, como *idêa* e *assemblêa*, e onde o acento não faz falta para distinguir estas de outras palavras.

O nosso moderno sistema de acentuação, com a identificação da sílaba tónica, tem a sua origem no final do século XIX e princípio do século XX. Tudo começou com iniciativas individuais, como o dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899. O dicionário está pejado de acentos: para assinalar a sílaba tónica e o timbre da vogal, como o próprio título da obra ilustra—*Nôvo Diccionário da Língua Portuguêza*.

A grafia oficial aprovada em Portugal em 1911 e a brasileira de 1943, que basicamente instituíram a nossa ortografia atual, foram mais comedidas: os padrões mais comuns—como paroxítonas acabadas em *a(s), e(s)* e *o(s)* (*cabra, bode, chibo*) ou oxítonas acabadas em *i(s), u(s), l, r, z* (*colibri, peru, papel, azar, rapaz*), etc.—não levam acento, ficando estes reservados para as exceções. Mas mantiveram ou introduziram o acento circunflexo em inúmeras palavras como, nessas grafias, *acôrdo, acêrto, sôbre, sêde*, não porque fosse necessário para identificar a sílaba tónica, mas para as distinguir de *(eu) acordo, (eu) acerto, sobre* (de *sobrar*), *sede* (‘quartel-general’). A esmagadora maioria destes acentos diferenciais foi abolida em Portugal em 1945, e no Brasil em 1971. O Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 aboliu mais uns tantos dos poucos que tinham sobrevivido, e agora restam bem poucos (ver [esta pergunta sobre este último ponto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/392/por-que-n%C3%A3o-existe-mais-o-acento-diferencial-em-palavras-homogr%C3%A1ficas-para-p)).

E pronto, aqui está por alto a história do acento circunflexo desde a sua origem grega atá ao uso atual no português.

Comment: Gostei das informações, Jacinto. Era tudo o que eu queria ter escrito, mas fiquei  com medo de deixar a resposta muito comprida e no final vocês não aceitarem.

Comment: @tuca Mas a ideia é haver uma pergunta, e depois uma ou várias respostas. Tu fizeste a pergunta. Eu escrevi uma resposta. Outra coisa: compreendeste bem as passagens de escrita antiga que eu incluí? Eu, ao princípio, tive de ler com calma, por vezes voltar atrás, para compreender.

Comment: Verdade. Entendi tudo. Mas o que percebi então, é que o circunflexo, atualmente continua sendo muito menos usado, se comparado ao acento agudo.

Comment: @tuca Isso é verdade, pelo menos no português europeu. Creio que a razão é a seguinte. Atualmente usamos os acentos quase só para assinalar a sílaba tónica, e a sílaba tónica normalmente mais frequentemente é aberta (acento agudo) do que fechada (acento circunflexo). O português do Brasil têm mais acentos circunflexos que o europeu, porque tem muitas vogais fechadas onde no português europeu são abertas: Antônio vs. António; gênero vs. género, etc. No século XIX era ainda mais raro: li algumas obras na grafia da época, e quase não se encontra o circunflexo.

Comment: Outra coisa: para poder me concentrar melhor nas perguntas e respostas, acho que deverei alternar e concentrar-me pelo menos um dia com outros Stacks, tais como o espanhol, inglês ou alemão. (respondendo ao seu comentário anterior a respeito de pesquisar com calma sobre perguntas e respostas).