# Sinônimo de "tomador de decisão" em uma palavra

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, expressões-idiomáticas, sinônimos

Costumo dizer que o indivíduo responsável por tomar decisões é o ***tomador de decisões***. Essa expressão é de uso corrente, pelo menos no sul e no sudeste do Brasil. Por exemplo:

> "(...) assuntos específicos relativos à administração pública municipal, analisando as finanças do município do ponto de vista do **tomador de decisões**". Fonte: MATIAS, Alberto Borges; CAMPELLO, Carlos AG. Administração financeira municipal. Atlas, 2000.

Eu queria saber se há alguma palavra que expresse o mesmo significado e que seja de uso frequente. Conheço ***decisor*** e ***julgador***, mas nunca as escuto. [Esta página](https://www.dicio.com.br/decisor/) diz que ***decisor*** é sinônimo de ***julgador***.

No caso de ***decisor***, até encontrei trabalhos que a utilizam, como o artigo "Um estudo sobre a desconexão entre usuários e desenvolvedores de sistemas de informação e sua influência na obtenção de informação pelo **decisor**" (STÁBILE, Samuel, 2001).

Para ***julgador*** encontrei algumas referências associadas à área jurídica, tais como "Decisão judicial nos crimes sexuais: o **julgador** e o réu interior" (DIVAN, Gabriel Antinolfi, 2010) e "A dignidade da pessoa humana e o papel do **julgador**" (NUNES, Luiz Antônio Rizzatto, 2007).

Tenho interesse em PT-BR e PT-PT.

Comment: Para mim, *decisor* é normalíssimo da silva. É o que nós usamos em Economia. Em Portugal, mas creio que no Brasil também. *Julgador* não me parece a mesma coisa.

Comment: @Jacinto, de fato, pelas pesquisas que fiz, não pareceu ser exatamente a mesma coisa. Diz neste site que é sinônimo: https://www.dicio.com.br/decisor/

Comment: Isso deve ser mais em tribunais: quem julga decide.

Comment: @Jacinto exato, como consta na pergunta, apesar de dadas como sinônimos naquela página, encontrei somente referências ligadas à justiça. Não conheces outra palavra com o mesmo significado de decisor?

Comment: Eight, não me estou a lembrar de mais nenhuma. Há outras que em certos contextos implicam capacidade decisória, mas que em si mesmo não significam 'decisor'. Por exemplo, em Microeconomia, que é em grande parte o estudo da tomada de decisão em mercados, *consumidor* e *produtor* referem-se a entidades que tomam decisões, mas a palavra em si mesmo não significa 'decisor'. *Agente* também implica nalguns contextos capacidade decisória; mas noutros o agente pode agir a mando de outro.

Comment: julgador é jurídico, se ve em textos jurídicos, atos, etc. Se refer ao juiz do  caso ou ao juiz em termos das leis etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para *tomador de decisão* numa só palavra, a escolha evidente para mim é ***decisor***. *Julgador* poderá implicar capacidade decisória em certos contextos, mas não é um sinónimo geral de *decisor*. O Aulete não dá [*julgador*](http://www.aulete.com.br/julgador) e [*decisor*](http://www.aulete.com.br/decisor) como sinónimos; o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=BVd8y) e o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) também não. Aquilo é idiossincrasia do Dicio.

***Decisor*** é um termo comum em Portugal. Procurei no [Google com restrição ao Brasil](https://www.google.pt/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=os%20decisores&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_pt&cr=countryBR&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) e também encontrei imensos resultados. Aparecem sobretudo em textos algo técnicos, nomeadamente do meio académico, especialmente da área da Economia, Administração e Marketing. Já em Portugal se encontra, por exemplo, *decisores políticos* na comunicação social.

Mostro os números de resultados da busca no Google. Em Portugal parece haver uma preferência marcada por *decisor* relativamente a *tomador de decisão*, coisa que eu já esperava; no Brasil é o inverso, mas menos marcado.

**Resultados da busca no Google**

```
                                Brasil      Portugal
O decisor                         279         265
Os decisores                      293         367
O tomador de decisão/ões        224/262      40/24
Os tomadores de decisão/ões     234/258      93/51
```

Deixo abaixo alguns exemplos, todos do Brasil (os negritos são todos meus). Nota que *decisor* convive com *tomada de decisão*. Isto não me surpreende. Eu tenho feito pesquisa na área da tomada de decisão. Como *decisão* sugere mais imediatamente ‘aquilo que foi decidido’, eu prefiro falar de *tomada de decisão* ou *processo de decisão* quando me refiro ao processo e não ao seu resultado; para me referir àquele que decide, *decisor* serve perfeitamente.

> *Vieses do **decisor** que podem influenciar sua **tomada de decisão***
>   [(Tese de Mestrado de Paulo D. T. Silva, EBAPE, Rio de Janeiro, 2007.)](http://bibliotecadigital.fgv.br/dspace/bitstream/handle/10438/8744/1418400.pdf?sequence=1)
>
> **O decisor** é aquele que pode influenciar o processo decisório […]
>   [“A Importância da **Tomada de Decisão**”, *Portal Educação*, 2012.)](https://www.portaleducacao.com.br/educacao/artigos/16238/a-importancia-da-tomada-de-decisao)
>
> Situação: são os aspectos ambientais, ou indicativos do estado da natureza que envolvem a cena da **tomada de decisão** e consequentemente o **decisor**;
>   [(Eduardo Meireles, *Introdução à Teoria da Decisão*, Unilago, 2009.)](http://www.unilago.com.br/download/arquivos/21016/Adm._Sist._teoria_da_decisao__-_Eduardo_USP.pdf)
>
> os grandes **decisores empresariais e governamentais** estão interessados nas soluções que obtenham os melhores resultados para suas empresas e seus países.
>   [(Carlos F. S. Gomes e Luiz F. A. M. Gomes, “A Função de Decisão Multicritério”, Revista do Mestrado em Administração e Desenvolvimento Empresarial, nº3, 2002.)](http://www.estacio.br/revistamade/03/artigo8.asp)
>
> Antes de iniciar os passos a serem cumpridos pelos DECISORES dentro de um processo decisório, faz-se mister apresentar cinco pontos fundamentais do processo decisório
>   [(*Orientação para os Decisores*, Escola de Guerra Naval, 2015.)](https://www.egn.mar.mil.br/arquivos/eem/eem/decisor.htm)

Comment: decisor é uma tradução do inglês decision maker. Não existia antes (há, digamos, 25 anos atràs mas ou menos) em português....

Comment: @Lambie "Que, affouto decisôr, e insano, o Vulgo / Sempre decide tudo, em tudo errado"— [Nuno Álvares Pereira Pato Moniz, *A Apparição*, 1818](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_SoRAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA56&dq=decisor&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNvauXivTQAhUBmxQKHaQkDcE4yAEQ6AEIiAIwJg#v=onepage&q=decisor&f=false).

Comment: Será que decisôr e decisor [a palavra moderna] seria a mesma coisa? ôr e or? Eu não sei. Precisaria procurar no Dicionário de História Empresarial Portuguesa, nos seus múltiples volumes. :)

Comment: @Lambie O ambiente não parece ser o empresariar, mas é "decisôr" que "sempre decido tudo". A grafia do século XIX era, nas palavras dum dicionarista da época, caótica, e cada um escrevia à sua maneira. Podes ver [nesta resposta minha sobre o acento circunflexo](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/qual-%C3%A9-a-origem-do-sinal-gr%C3%A1fico-circunflexo). Atenção que é uma resposta **muito longa** :)

Comment: Um decisor pode ser em qualquer "ambiente". A frase citada usa o termo em um contexto de administração pública. Acaba sendo a mesma coisa que um contexto de empresa etc.

Answer (score 3):

**"tomador de decisões"** é um termo genérico usado em administração de empresas e que vai corresponder a um determinado profissional dependendo do contexto. Na ausência de um termo mais simples, e descrito por apenas uma palavra, é o que vem sendo usado. O "tomador de decisões" pode ser:

- o diretor de uma escola
- um gerente de departamento
- um conselho administrativo
- um governador de estado ou província
- um presidente da república
- um médico ou uma junta médica frente a um caso grave
- o juiz de uma partida de futebol
- você ou sua esposa, ou ambos em conjunto, em sua casa
- etc.

> Todas as atividades que envolvem o planejamento precisam passar por um processo cuidadoso. Nos ambientes organizacionais existem várias atividades em que o gestor deve tomar as decisões corretas, ao longo do processo. O indivíduo responsável por tomar decisões pode ser um governador, o presidente da organização, um diretor técnico de uma escola, ou grupos, como entidades, conselhos de ministros, comitês, juri, etc. Estes são conhecidos como os atores do processo decisório que irão avaliar e se basear nos valores do sistema que está inserido. Juntamente com os atores estão todos aqueles que sofrem as consequências das decisões. Tanto para organizações públicas, quanto para privadas existem processos que envolvem o planejamento de projetos que necessitam do processo decisório para evitar possíveis problemas futuros e garantir a eficácia na decisão.  [**Tomada de Decisão nas Organizações**](http://www.okconcursos.com.br/apostilas/apostila-gratis/111-administracao-geral/162-tomada-de-decisao-nas-organizacoes#.WESRH_krJPY)

Answer (score 0):

Em Portugal usamos Decisor para isso.

Answer (score 0):

Decisor: Que ou quem decide ou tem o poder de decidir.

"decisor", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/decisor [consultado em 14-12-2016].

Comment: @CiMend, como as informações nas outras páginas pode mudar, poderia copiar elas para a tua resposta como citação?