# Uma palavra pode não receber acento por dois motivos?

Tags: acentuação

Por exemplo, "Heroico".

Essa palavra não é acentuada pois é paroxítona e a sílaba tônica é um ditongo aberto, ou seja, "he-**roi**-co", o ditongo aberto é o "**roi**".

Porém a palavra termina em O, e paroxítonas terminadas em O não recebe acento. Isso também seria motivo para a palavra não receber acento?﻿

Se sim, existe preferência para algum dos motivos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade nenhuma das tuas regras é válida. Por exemplo *gaúcho* e *ruído* são paroxítonas acabadas em *o* mas precisam de acento. E *Gláuber* (nome de homem) e *náilon* são também paroxítonas e levam acento num ditongo aberto. É verdade que são raras as paroxítonas com ditongos tónicos, abertos ou fechados, que precisem de acento gráfico; mas as condições que exigem acento nas paroxítonas não distinguem entre sílabas tónicas com ditongo ou vogal simples.

As regras de acentuação das paroxítonas vêm nas Bases IX e X do [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 (Portal da Língua Portuguesa)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990). A base X trata de paroxítonas e oxítonas, e ambas as bases distinguem entre acento aguado e circunflexo, que aqui não vem ao caso, de modo que eu creio que consigo sintetizar as regras de acentuação de paroxítonas de forma mais clara.

A grande maioria das paroxítonas não leva acento. Precisam de acento as que tem certas terminações que sem acento tornariam a palavra oxítona; e aquelas cujo *i* ou *u* tónico é precedido de outra vogal com a qual não forma ditongo (como *gaúcho*). *Heroico* não leva acento porque não está em nenhuma destas situações.

> **Levam acento paroxítonas terminadas em:**
>
> 1. ***l***: *estável, ágil, cônsul.* Contrasta com as oxítonas *papel, perfil, farol*.
> 2. ***n***: éden, náilon. Não conheço oxítonas contrastantes.
> 3. ***r***: ímpar, âmbar, Gláuber, gêiser. Contrasta com as oxítonas *paladar, comer, amor*.
> 4. ***x***: tórax, córtex. Contrasta com a oxítona *telex*.
> 5. ***ps***: bíceps, fórceps. Não conheço oxítonas contrastantes.
>
> **Levam acento paroxítonas cuja última sílaba contém:**
>
> 6. ***i***: júri, íris, hóquei, répteis, (se vós) *fizésseis, Elêusis*. Contrasta com as oxítonas *alibi,* (eu) *comi,* (tu) *sorris*, (vós) *fazeis*.
> 7. ***u***: álbum, álbuns, vírus, ânus. Contrasta com as oxítonas *fartum, urubu*.
> 8. ***~***: órfã, órfãs, órfão, órfãos, bênção, orégãos. Contrasta com as oxítonas *maçã, canção.*
>
> **Levam acento, com umas exceções, paroxítonas cuja sílaba tónica começa com *i* ou *u* precedido de outra vogal, com qual naturalmente não forma ditongo:**
>
> 9. *Gaúcho, saúde, conteúdo, ciúme, saída, faísca,* (ele) *saía,* (imperfeito, contrastar com subjuntivo *que ele saia*), (eles) *saíam, roíam*. Contrasta com as paroxítonas, em que o *i* ou *u* fazem parte de ditongo, *incauto, feudo, heroico, intuito*.
>
>    - Exceção 1. O *i* ou *u* forma sílaba com a consoante seguinte, *l, r, m, n*, ou é seguido de *nh* (e é nasalado, vê [esta pergunta acerca de *rainha*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/em-rainha-o-i-forma-s%C3%ADlaba-com-o-nh-o-acordo-ortogr%C3%A1fico-diz-que-sim)): *ainda, Coimbra, rainha, triunfo, demiurgo,* (se nós) *possuirmos*.
>    - Exceção 2. O *i* ou *u* tónico vem a seguir a um ditongo: *baiuca, cheiinho.*
>
> **Exceções a isto tudo**
>
> - É *ontem ele não **pôde** mas hoje **pode**;* este acento não é necessário para indicar a sílaba tónica; é meramente diferencial, para assinalar o timbre fechado no pretérito perfeito e assim permitir distingui-lo do presente *pode*, que tem timbre aberto. Ver [esta pergunta sobre acentos diferenciais](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/392/por-que-n%C3%A3o-existe-mais-o-acento-diferencial-em-palavras-homogr%C3%A1ficas-para-p).
> - Na norma europeia é opcional pôr-se acento agudo no pretérito perfeito dos verbos do primeiro grupo (infinitivo em *-ar*) *cantámos, levámos, amámos,* etc., para distinguir do presente *cantamos, levamos, amamos,* etc. Isto porque o *a* tónico é na linguagem-padrão fechado no presente e aberto no passado. No Brasil e alguns dialetos meridionais de Portugal o *a* tónico é sempre fechado, não se distinguindo aquelas formas verbais.

Comment: Que interessante, muito obrigado Jacinto!

Comment: @Filipi, na grafia anterior ao AO90 colocava-se acento agudo em todos ditongos abertos tónicos *éi, éu* e *ói* (independentemente da terminação da palavra).  O AO90 aboliu estes acentos nas paroxítonas (exceto nos casos previstos acima). Talvez venha daí a tua ideia que os ditongos abertos das paroxítonas não levam acento. Por exemplo, dantes era *paranóico*, agora é *paranoico*; no Brasil dantes era *protéico* e *assembléia*, agora é *proteico* e *assembleia* (em Portugal já era sem assento porque o *ei* dessas palavras é fechado no nosso sotaque).

Answer (score 0):

Estás a ver as coisas pelo prisma errado.

Deves assumir que as palavras não carecem de acento, a não ser em casos excecionais.

Por norma, palavras terminadas em `/[aeo](s|m|ns)?/` são graves e não precisam de acento.

Depois, há motivos pelos quais a palavra, mesmo sendo grave pode levar acento. Nomeadamente, por causa de um hiato que de outra forma seria pronunciado como ditongo (ex. fuido vs fluído) ou no caso especial do acento diferencial (ex. pode vs. pode) em que se coloca acento pontualmente em palavras que poderiam ser confundidas com outras.

No caso de heroico, não há motivo nenhum para ter de levar acento.